# H1 Tags and Anchor Text

Tags: seo, links, meta-keywords

I am building an image based website with no text space available on the Home Page. Can I turn the main Nav Menu links into H1 tags too? Will the site be punished by Search Engines from an SEO point of view for doing it this way?

```
<h1>
<a href="#">Landscape Photography</a>
<a href="#">Product Photography</a>
<a href="#">Portait Photography</a>
<a href="#">Food Photography</a>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image websites are hard to rank because search engines do not have much to work on. I know, I've been struggling with one too and adding an h1 made a big difference. Now, it does not have to be all h1 but at least a few headings.

It would be fair for you to use headings as links, assuming they point to the right gallery. One could do better if you managed to slip in an H1 for the content on the home page, say 'John Doe Photography' and then use H2 for each link to one of the category pages.

Comment: Actually, that is a great suggestion to use the H2 tag for the Main Nav links and squeeze a H1 in somewhere if I can. Thx

Answer (score 0):

h1 tag should be only one on the page and it should contains the most important info about the page.
Intersection of tag H1 and a is a bad signal for search engine. These tags should not be crossed.
In your case I would suggest you to describe in H1 on your page the most important words you want this page to rank high in search engine.

Comment: You can have as many H1 tags on a page as you want without getting a penalty. My question was about wrapping the Nav Links in a H1 tag!